# What determines the Hostage Rescue timer?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In maps like `cs_office`, `cs_militia`, `cs_assault`, and `cs_italy`, the gamemode there involves rescuing at least one hostage. But when you find a hostage and hold the rescue key, sometimes the rescue timer is set to **4 seconds**, and sometimes the timer is set to **1 second.**

What exactly determines the duration of the timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like a player buys a defuse kit in order to reduce the time it takes to defuse a bomb, he or she can buy a rescue kit as a Counter Terrorist. It exists at the same slot as with the defuse kit in the buy menu.
If the player has a rescue kit, the rescue time will be reduced to one second just like you've observed.

[image]